# How is the Value of JavaScript this Keyword Set According to ECMAScript EvaluateCall?

Tags: javascript

If we have the following code block, when we call `obj.getX()`, which step does this correspond to according to the spec?

How does the js engine evaluate `obj.getX()` when it comes to setting the `this` value to the context object on the left hand side?

```js
const obj = {
  x: 1,
  getX() {
    return x
  }
}
```

The spec states in [EvaluateCall](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#sec-evaluatecall)

> #### 13.3.6.2 EvaluateCall ( func, ref, arguments, tailPosition )
>
> The abstract operation EvaluateCall takes arguments func (an ECMAScript language value), ref (an ECMAScript language value or a Reference Record), arguments (a Parse Node), and tailPosition (a Boolean) and returns either a normal completion containing an ECMAScript language value or an abrupt completion. It performs the following steps when called:
>
> ```
> 1. If ref is a Reference Record, then
>   a. If IsPropertyReference(ref) is true, then
>     i. Let thisValue be GetThisValue(ref).
>   b. Else,
>     i. Let refEnv be ref.[[Base]].
>     ii. Assert: refEnv is an Environment Record.
>     iii. Let thisValue be refEnv.WithBaseObject().
> 2. Else,
>   a. Let thisValue be undefined.
> 3. Let argList be ? ArgumentListEvaluation of arguments.
> 4. If func is not an Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 5. If IsCallable(func) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> 6. If tailPosition is true, perform PrepareForTailCall().
> 7. Return ? Call(func, thisValue, argList).
> ```

Comment: `obj.getX()` is a [_CallMemberExpression_ : _MemberExpression Arguments_](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-CallMemberExpression). Here are the [relevant runtime semantics](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation) where the _MemberExpression_ is evaluated as _ref_ which is later used to derive the `this` value. Related: [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](/q/3127429/4642212).